# Winston log configuration for showing objects

Tags: node.js, winston

I get the following output:

```
2019-09-03T13:49:34.203Z debug: [object Object]
```

With the code:

```
log.add(
  new transports.Console({
    format: combine(
      format.errors({ stack: true }),
      format.splat(),
      format.colorize(),
      format.simple(),
      timestamp(),
      printf(
        ({ level, message, timestamp }): string => {
          return `${timestamp} ${level}: ${message}`;
        }
      )
    )
  })
);
```

However I'd like my object to be displayed serialized, not as an `[object Object]`. How does one do this in Winston?

Comment: I havn't used winston before but, can't you just do ```return `${timestamp} ${level}: ${JSON.stringify(message)}``` if it's an object?

Comment: @MichaelSorensen That serializes the object though, so I have to parse it again after the log :/

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below code and whenever you want to log message along with object, just need `Logger.debug('message goes here', object)`

```
const customFormat = printf(({ timestamp, level, message, ...rest }) => {
    let restString = JSON.stringify(rest, undefined, 2);
    restString = restString === '{}' ? '' : restString;

    return `[${timestamp}] ${level}: ${message} ${restString}`;
});

const format = combine(errors({ stack: true }), timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' }), customFormat);

const transports = [
    new winston.transports.Console({
        format: combine(splat(), prettyPrint()),
    }),
    new winston.transports.File({
        filename: 'logs/all.log',
        format: combine(json()),
        handleExceptions: true,
        handleRejections: true,
    }),
    // new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
    //  filename: 'logs/%DATE%-all.log',
    //  datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    //  zippedArchive: true,
    //  maxFiles: '1d',
    //  format: combine(json()),
    //  handleExceptions: true,
    //  handleRejections: true,
    // }),
];
```